# How to remove rounded corners from an Icon in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following list view in my jQuery mobile app  with data split icon delete , the icon appears as circle shape i want to remove the rounded corners of the icon so the icon will be  a square shape as in the photo  . I have used data-corners="false" , border-radius= 0 but it didnt work in jquery mobile 1.4.0 please any help would be greatly appreciated ..

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">

</div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true"  data-filter="true" data-filter-  placeholder="Search" data-split-icon="delete"  style="margin-top: 40px;"   > 

<li class="RTLList" > <a href="#"><img  src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/_assets/img/album-bb.jpg" /> element 1 </a><a    href="#"  id="split-icon1" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried this its working in jQuery mobile 1.3.2 but didnt in 1.4.0

```
#page1 *{
  border-top-left-radius:0!important;
  border-top-right-radius:0!important;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0!important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius:0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG icons are now used in jQuery Mobile 1.4 with a pseudo selector `:after`. All you need is to remove `border-radius` on `ui-btn-icon-notext` class.

```
.ui-btn-icon-notext:after {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```